# Ansible: ansible.cfg from current directory?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to make ansible first search for `.ansible.cfg` in current directory, instead of always defaulting to home directory? Similarly like many configs work, where it looks in your current dir, then parent (and so on) to find relevant config.

Yet with ansible it always uses config from one place.

When I started deploying with different inventory in mind, I forgot about that, thinking that it will use my local config (where I set path to another inventory, different roles etc), but it of course it used default options and deployed in wrong environments, wrong things..

Is there a way to properly manage multiple configs with ansible?

Say I have dir `my-ansible` and in that dir, I have `.ansible.cfg`, so doing `cd my-ansible` and `ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml` it would use config in that directory, not in my home dir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ansible.cfg`, not `.ansible.cfg` in current directory, see

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file

Changes can be made and used in a configuration file which will be searched for in the following order:

- ANSIBLE_CONFIG (environment variable if set)
- ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
- ~/.ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
- /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

Comment: Oh its non hidden file.. Thanks, thought it supposed to be hidden in current dir too.

Comment: It actually makes a lot of sense, imagine if someone else is working on your playbooks too, it will be easier for them to see non-hidden files and to check them for some crucial alterations than to stare into nothingness and question their sanity if something doesn't work by default

Comment: Not saying it does not make sense. Its just I thought it had to be hidden:). Its OK that it needs to be not hidden. I guess im used to many other config files being hidden, so implied that for ansible too.